# C++: stop RPC service

Tags: c++, rpc

from my C++ source, I am starting an RPC service calling `svc_run()`. Everything looks just fine and I can see my service running if I type `rpcinfo -p` in my terminal.

Now I am working on a "cleanup" function which should stop this service and remove it from the `rpcinfo -p` list.

How can I do that? At the moment I am only able to stop it using `sudo rpcinfo -d program version` in my terminal. How can I do this from my source file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I found out how to do this. Actually I faced some unexpected difficulties. The standard way to do this would be to use this:

```
svc_unregister(PROGID, VERSION)
```

but somehow, it did not work for me. After lots of trial and some online help (http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-nfs/msg05619.html) I was able to delete the RPC service calling:

```
pmap_unset(PROGID, VERSION);
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: this call "pmap_unset" is normally used in the beginning before svcudp_create f.x.
It did not stop processQue for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `void svc_exit(void)` function. For more detailed description please refer to rpc_svc_calls chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this force stop of svc_run(), however did not find a solution, I however made the svc_run() stop from within the registered function and then it stopped - perhaps this could help you - please look at this : [svc_exit Subroutine](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.commtrf1/svc_exit.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The 'nicest' solution is to use both DevCpp's and Danilo's solution combined:

- Among the RPC functions of your server, define one function which, when called by the client, executes svc_exit(). This will let your RPC server return from the svc_run() loop. Now you can either extend your RPC client application or create a separate client application to terminate your server.
- In your RPC server's main program, right after the call to svc_run(), execute 'pmap_unset(PROGID, VERSION);'. This will let rpcbind unregister your RPC address.
- Then do the usual cleanup of your application.

This combination allows your RPC server to run as a demon, i.e. without user interaction, while still offering a clean exit without having to cancel the process.